# REGEX, remove whitespace and all other characters

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

trying to convert this example

```
Some Nice Article on amazon https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/ADKLHJADK/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B01J7LLL9Q&pd_rd_r=a8c7bb4b-49da-11e8-ad28-014ae5dc2f42&pd_rd_w=9QOk2&pd_rd_wg=zc1s7&pf_rd_m=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=VF3C7MDNZ741H8S13AYV&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=1c175abe-9bc7-490b-bbe1-2caf7e752c98&pf_rd_i=desktop&linkCode=ll1
```

to this

```
https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/YXZ91ALI91/
```

what is the correct or best way to handle this in java with regex?
because my option looks really dirty...

```
https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]/
```

Working Solution for getting a amazon link out:

First Part till | is for every desktop copy and paste and everything after is for when you copy with the share button of the mobile app.

https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/[^/]+/?|https://www.amazon.de/dp/[^/]+/

Comment: can you please define all characters that need to be removed

Comment: If the product is always a known length (10), then `[\\p{Alnum}]{10}` would be better based upon your current option. However, the question seems broader than your option.

Comment: from what I see is you need the all the characters within the first 6 slashes

Comment: @D.'s every character before "https://" and every character after the the 10 alpha numeric length and the /

Comment: it's time for you to try something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex will look like this:

```
https:\/\/www.amazon.de\/gp\/product\/[^\/]+\/?
```

`[^\/]` means "everything that's not slash"

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/wwFmMw/1

Comment: Thank you! Editted my post.

Here the working solution for every kind of amazon url:

Comment: https:\/\/www.amazon.de\/gp\/product\/[^\/]+\/?|https:\/\/www.amazon.de\/dp\/[^\/]+\/

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches. This approach works assuming that it is the section after product.

```
 Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^.*(https://.*/product/[^\\/]*?/).*");
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String inp = "Some Nice Article on amazon "
            + "https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/ADKLHJADK/ref=as_li_ss_tl"
            + "?ie=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B01J7LLL9Q&pd_rd_r"
            + "=a8c7bb4b-49da-11e8-ad28-014ae5dc2f42&pd_rd_w"
            + "=9QOk2&pd_rd_wg=zc1s7&pf_rd_m=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r"
            + "=VF3C7MDNZ741H8S13AYV&pf_rd_t="
            + "36701&pf_rd_p=1c175abe-9bc7-490b-bbe1-2caf7e752c98&pf_rd_i"
            + "=desktop&linkCode=ll1";


    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^.*(https://.*/product/[^\\/]*?/).*");

    Matcher m = pat.matcher(inp);

    if (m.matches() && m.groupCount() > 0) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }

}
```

The idea is to find the start of the "https:", then anything, then "product/", then anything until the next "/".

Resultant output:

> https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/ADKLHJADK/

Answer (score 0):

**One line solution :**

`String result = myStrValue.replaceAll('.*(https://www\.amazon\.de/gp/product/\w+/).*', '$1');`.

\w+ means at least one word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]

Try the java regex here : https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output